# Unable to Upgrade from 11.10 to 12.04

Tags: upgrade

I am unable to upgrade from 11.10 to 12.04. After the download completed and other process the final message comes as

The upgrade has aborted. Your system could be in an unusable state. A recovery will run now (`dpkg --configure -a`).
The only option tab is   `Close` .

What should I do? I try 5 times but the same thing is happening even I restart the laptop.

I am using `Windows8` consumer preview as other boot option.

Comment: seems u can still use  ubuntu.Try a clean install after backing up your data.

Comment: You should not reinstall just because of a little problem with a package!!!

Answer (score 0):

You should open a terminal and execute the command from the error, but with sudo (because the normal doesn't have the required rights):

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

When executing a command with sudo, you'll have to type your password blindly (there won't be any stars indicating how many characters you typed) and then press enter.

If that works, you should execute the command

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```

to solve other package problems (there will probably be some).

Then you should update your system:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```